# Writing contains() for a generic collection

Tags: java, generics, collections

I'm writing a skiplist class in java as an excercise. I've written a class called `SkipListInternal<E>` which contains the actual skiplist. I've also made a wrapper class called `SkipListSet<E>` which implement the `SortedSet<E>` interface and contains an instance of `SkipListInternal<E>`.

Among other things, `SkipListInternal<E>` contains a method `E find(E e)` which returns the element equal to `e` if it is present, and otherwise returns null.

When writing the `boolean contains(Object o)` (inherited from `Collection<E>` via `SortedSet<E>`) method I noticed that its argument is an Object and not an E. I intended to do something like this, but is not possible due to type erasure:

```
public class SkipListSet<E> implements SortedSet<E>{
   private SkipListInternal<E> skiplist;

   ...

   public boolean contains(Object o){
       if (!(o instanceof E)) return false;
       return skiplist.find((E) o) != null;
   }

   ...

}
```

Since it can't be done this way, how should I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strictly speaking such an implementation would be wrong.

The reason for this is that even if an object is not of type `E`, it could still return `true` on an `equals()` call.

Assume for a second, that you've got a class like this:

```
public class FakeString {
  private final String value;

  public FakeString(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    return value.hashCode();
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return value.equals(o);
  }
}
```

Then this code would print `true`:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
System.out.println(strings.contains(new FakeString("bar")));
```

And just to clarify: this behaviour is **intended** and is the reason why `contains()` takes an `Object` instead of `E`. The same is true for `remove()`, by the way.

Comment: Is it really intended behaviour? The rules for `equals` require the implementation to be symmetric, but your `FakeString` breaks that rule. And all built-in `SortedSet` implementations (`TreeSet`, the skip-list implementation from java.util.concurrent) uses Comparator/Comparableand does not call `equals` at all.

Comment: @Dirk, The same problem applies to Comparator/Comparable.

Comment: @Dirk: The `TreeSet` documentation even claims that it "[..] fails to obey the general contract of the `Set` interface."

Comment: @Dirk: and while my sample violates the `equals()` contract it's easy to construct a sample with `PersonData` and `PersonStub` where the `equals()` construct is held up and you can still remove a `PersonData` object from a `List<PersonData>` using a `PersonStub` as the argument.

Comment: Jup. Pretend my initial comment as being "withdrawn" (kept for reference, though :-) Anyhow: the OP wants to implement a `SortedSet`. As your answer is the current favourite... Maybe you could add a few sentences about using `Comparator`/`Comparable` instead of `equals` in the `contains` method, as having an O(n) implementation if an O(log n) is possible due to the chosen data structure might be worthwhile.

Comment: The fact that `contains` accepts an `Object` is because there is nothing wrong with asking a collection of `Cat` whether it contains an `Animal`.  If the `Animal` happens to be a `Cat`, the collection may contain it.  If it happens to be a `Dog`, the collection may simply report that it does not contain it.  If the collection notices that the `Dog` is not a type of object that can exist within it, then it can report that it doesn't contain the object without looking any further; if it doesn't notice, it will find none of the items equal the `Dog`.

Comment: It's a silly reason, because it does away with all the goodness that comes with generics. Now it's error prone because #contains() accepts any type, not just the type that is defined being in the collection via generics. If it's not defined being in the collection through generics, why should it be reasonable to still ask if it maybe is contained in said collection? It's just silly.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `contains()` is from `java.util.Collection`, We are supposed to follow the `Collection.contains()` **contract**. Because throwing `ClassCastException` is an optional behavior, it's correct to return false in your code when cast fails. So I think your implementation comply with the contract.

```
        /**
         * Returns true if this collection contains the specified element.
         * More formally, returns true if and only if this collection
         * contains at least one element e such that
         * (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).
         *
         * @param o element whose presence in this collection is to be tested
         * @return <tt>true</tt> if this collection contains the specified
         *         element
         * @throws ClassCastException if the type of the specified element
         *         is incompatible with this collection (optional)
         * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null and this
         *         collection does not permit null elements (optional)
         */
         boolean contains(Object o);
```

Comment: +1 : since the contract specifies that ClassCastException may be thrown if the given object is not of the right type, I would just cast the object to the generic type E.

Comment: @JBNizet: If I have a collection of `Animal`, and I want to ask a collection of `Cat` whether it contains each of the items therein, there should be no problem with that.  When asked if it contains `Fido`, it would seem more logical for it to simply reply "No, it doesn't", than to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

@Joaschim comment is correct for standard collections, however if you want a checked collection I suggest you check what can be added, and not optimise for the lookups of invalid types (unless you want to throw an Exception)  You can do something like.

```
public class SkipListSet<E> implements SortedSet<E>{
   private final Class<E> eClass;
   private final SkipListInternal<E> skiplist;

   ...
   public boolean add(Object o) {
       if(!eClass.isInstanceOf(o))
    // OR
       if(eClass != o.getClass())
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type "+o.getClass()+" is not a "+eClass);
       skiplist.add(o);
   }

   public boolean contains(Object o){
       // if (!(o instanceof E)) return false; // don't need to optmise for this.
       return skiplist.find((E) o) != null;
   }

   ...

}
```

BTW: Java has a builtin thread safe `ConcurrentSkipListSet` and `ConcurrentSkipListMap` You might find it interesting to read the source for this. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the built-in classes! I had managed to completely miss those.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a sorted set implementation to work, the elements of the set have to have an ordering. This may either be "natural" (i.e., the elements implement `Comparable`) or "imposed" (by using an explicit `Comparator` during set construction).

So, the first thing is, that you'd probably rather use the ordering defined for the set elements (after all, you are implementing a `SortedSet`!) instead of `equals` in `contains` for efficiency. I assume, that you are already using an ordering in your internal  `SkipListInternal<E>` -- how'd you maintain the `Sorted` in `SortedSet` given only `equals`?

The fact that `contains` is actually declared as `contains(Object key)` in the interface is really unfortunate. I'd do, what the `TreeMap` implementation does (which is the underlying container for `TreeSet`, the standard `SortedSet` from the collections framework):

```
if (comparator != null)
    return getEntryUsingComparator(key);
if (key == null)
    throw new NullPointerException();
Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
```

i.e., cast, assuming the client application using your collection behaves sanely.