# Why does my java class implement methods I don't expect?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I have this interface:

```
public interface IDeck<T extends IDeck<T,S>,S extends ICard<S>> extends Comparable<T>, Collection<S>{
    public Set<S> getDeck();
    public void setDeck(Set<S> newDeck);
}
```

And I then make a class implement it, here is the header and the first few methods:

```
public class PlayingCardDeck implements IDeck<PlayingCardDeck,PlayingCard> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PlayingCardDeck o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
```

Good so far, I want it to be comparable.

```
    @Override
    public boolean add(PlayingCard e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

Yup, it can contain PlayingCards

```
    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends PlayingCard> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

This is Ok I think, so long as the collection element extends PlayingCard, though this doesn't match the `add(PlayingCard e)` method.

```
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

Hang on? Why is the type here `Object` and not `PlayingCard` ?

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

So any array has to be of Objects, not PlayingCards?

Why am I getting 'weird' functions implemented from my interface, and not the generics I supplied? What have I missed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because [`Collection.contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) has `Object` as its parameter.  It's not defined as `Collection.contains(E)`. As for why that is, you can find a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992047/writing-contains-for-a-generic-collection).

Comment: I always wondered if there is anyone out there, just one person, who actually used this behaviour to do a good thing. Because there obviously is _a lot_ of people who find it irritating.

Comment: @Slanec The more I read of that answer and the comments, the more I think this exists for backwards compatibility.

Comment: +1 and it's not for backward compatibility. `contains`, `remove`, etc. take `Object` because `equals` takes `Object` and their contracts delegate to the `equals` contract.

Comment: The issue isn't just that they delegate to the `equals` contract, but rather that there is nothing inherently wrong about asking a collection of `Cat` whether it contains something that may or may not be a `Cat`.  If the thing in question isn't a `Cat`, the collection can simply reply "No, I don't contain that".

Answer (score 3):

Because `public Object[] toArray()` is declared in the interface `java.util.Collection`, and is not generic. As well as `contains(Object o)`. They are declared that way (non-generic) in the interface you implement.

Comment: I think here you could actually replace it with `public PlayingCard[] to Array()` using covariant return types.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline care to explain?

Comment: @Pureferret You can tighten the return type of an implemented/overridden method (from J2SE 5.0). `PlayingCard[]` is a subtype (specialisation) of `Object[]`, although it shouldn't really be so.